# How to wait till scroll is finished in Cypress without dealing with heights of elements

Tags: javascript, cypress

how to wait the acynchronus scrollIntoView without using `cy.wait(XXX)` or comparing view/element heights?

Here is what i thought to be like:

```
const cyBrick = cy.get(selector);
    cyBrick.scrollIntoView().then( _ => {
      cyBrick
        .then(([$brick]) => {
          const brickBody = $brick.getBoundingClientRect();
          cyBrick.trigger('mousedown', {which: 1, pageX: brickBody.x, pageY: brickBody.y});
          ...
        });
    });
```

In my case i'm testing dragAndDrop so i need

1. to scroll to an element to be dragged;
2. mouseDown on the element
3. scroll to target container and so on...

Also i tried a custom command

```
//commands.js
Cypress.Commands.add('scrollIntoViewAndUseThen', {prevSubject: true}, (subject) => {
  cy.wrap(subject).scrollIntoView().as('scrolling');
  cy.wait('@scrolling');
});

//mytest.spec.js
cyBrick.scrollIntoViewAndUseThen().then( _ => ...
```

But roots only are allowed to use @;

At this moment i use workaround with wait
`cyBrick.scrollIntoView().wait(500)`

PS: i read in docs that **scrollToView** allows to chain **should** accertion only

Answer (score 2):

I stuck with similar issue using cy.scrollTo() on an Angular app with a lot of animation. Cypress proceeds to next commands before the scrolling is finished.
I tried many combinations and found adding following options/values worked. These options can be used in scrollIntoView() too:

- easing (the easing animation): linear
- duration (Scrolls over the duration (in ms)): 100

The actual code looklikes this

```
cy.scrollTo('bottom', { easing: 'linear',duration: 100 }).then(() => { 
    // commands need to be executed after the scrolling is finished
});
```